# Error trying to "Reverse Engineer Code First" MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to follow [this tutorial video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) on the Entity framework. I am using VS2010 Professional.

I installed the `Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4` and am currently on the step of right clicking my project and clicking `Entity Framework > Reverse Engineer Code First`.

I change the data source to `MySQL Database` and enter my connection information. The connection test succeeds, but clicking OK to proceed results in this error message:

> Wrong Parameter. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I noticed that when I check the "save my password" checkbox when entering my connection data, the VS status bar at the bottom says "Loading schema information..." for a few seconds before the error appears. When this box is unchecked the error appears immediately after clicking OK.

Also, when the error appears the status bar says "An error occured while reverse engineering Code First. See the Output window for details." However, the output window remains empty.

Does anyone know what might be going on there?

Comment: I think you need at least VS 2012 and the EF 6 designer tools for PT Beta 4 to work

Comment: if that doesn't work you can try with this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838 it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 can reverse engineer MySQL 5.x databases into code first EF6 classes under VS2013
It claims to support Visual Studio 2013, 2012, 2010, but I have not tested other frameworks or IDE's. The tutorial you linked claims to require 2012 or 2013.

Power Tools available at: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d